# MongoDB Sum with existing query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to translate this SQL statement into MongoDB:

```
SELECT sum(cores) from [MongoDB Query] GROUP by cluster;
```

However, I already have this query executed to find the machines with the relevant parameters filtered.

I would like to SUM on this already executed query and GROUP by cluster

```
Machine.find(query).exec(function(err, machines) {

 Machine.distinct( "cluster", query ) //Its possible to run a distinct on this query


});
```

I am happy to use a solution using MongoDB or another javascript solution.

Comment: Core documentation. [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) where the answer is right there.

Comment: Can you aggregate on an existing query?

Comment: You only need submit one simple "aggregation query". It consists of "pipeline stages" and particularly [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/). Keep reading and you will learn something.

Comment: @Corbin See the linked dupe; you can prepend a `{$match: query}` stage to the `aggregate` pipeline to perform a query before the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation will allow for all grouping logic. Try this

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$group":{_id:"$cluster",sum:{"$sum":"$cores"}}}])
```